# Can I make MSYS2 suitable for yocto compilation?

Tags: yocto, msys2

So I am working on Win10 and I've worked with yocto in different Virtualizations on Ubuntu (Docker, QEMU and VirtualBox).

Now my goal is to get "the most native" environment on Windows. I am not sure if that is even possible but as far as I know, MSYS2 is fully POSIX-compliant. So I wondered if it'd be possible to compile a yocto build in the MSYS2 shell. I found most of the packages needed for compilation and I tried to start a build but I get some weird errors I can't really find a solution for. Before posting them here I wanted to ask if what I am trying is even possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

Window Subsystem for Linux version 2 *might* work, but version 1 didn't.

99% of Linux software needs to be built on a Linux system, not just one that is sort-of POSIXy.  If WSL2 doesn't work you'll need a proper virtual machine.

Comment: Okay yeah thats why I thought. I'm just gonna stick with Docker probably, I like the lightweight environment and the way you can work with containers. Thank you for your time and your contribution to yocto. I have seen your name so many times while building and testing.